# Using JSONWithPadding (Jersey) with alternative mime-type

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

When using Jersey and JSONWithPadding with Accept header I'm having problems making requests with this header

**Accept:application/vnd-foo.bar+javascript** (should return jsonp)

I'm getting the following message:

```
Feb 05, 2014 11:46:29 AM com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONWithPaddingProvider writeTo
SEVERE: A message body writer for Java type, [com.example.SomeEntity@4fc0e1e3], and MIME media type, application/vnd-foo.bar+javascript; charset=UTF-8, was not found.
```

Making requests with the following headers work just fine

**Accept:application/json** (returns json)
**Accept:application/vnd-foo.bar+json** (returns json)
**Accept:application/javascript** (returns jsonp)

I have not explicitly configured the service to handle application/vnd-foo.bar+json like application/json so I would expect application/vnd-foo.bar+javascript to be handled like application/javascript.

```
@GET
@Produces({ "application/json", "application/vnd-foo.bar+json", "application/javascript",
    "application/vnd-foo.bar+javascript" })
public JSONWithPadding get(@QueryParam("callback") String callback) {
    return new JSONWithPadding(someListOfObjects, callback);
}
```

Any ideas on how to have application/vnd-foo.bar+javascript being handled like application/javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you need to extend JSONP `MessageBodyWriter` called `JSONWithPaddingProvider` from Jersey 1. It's unfortunate that `JSONWithPaddingProvider#isJavascript()` is private otherwise it would be easier:

```
@Provider
public class CustomJSONWithPaddingProvider extends JSONWithPaddingProvider {

    @Override
    public void writeTo(final JSONWithPadding t,
                        final Class<?> type,
                        final Type genericType,
                        final Annotation[] annotations,
                        final MediaType mediaType,
                        final MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders,
                        final OutputStream entityStream)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        final boolean isJavascript = mediaType
                .getSubtype().endsWith("+javascript");
        final MediaType mt = isJavascript ?
                new MediaType("application", "javascript") : mediaType;

        super.writeTo(t, type, genericType, annotations, mt, httpHeaders, entityStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is easy enough ;-) Thanks!